# insert data into MYSQL using PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

hi im trying to insert data in mysql using  array, can someone please look at my code, i cant seem to make it work.

this is my post.php

```
/* POST.PHP */
$post_id = somefunction();
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];

$myarray = array('','$title','$body','$rowId');
insertToDB($myarray);
```

and this is inside my function.php

```
function insertToDB($myArray) {
    $db = dbConnect(); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO `posts`(`id`, `title`, `body`, `post_id`) VALUES ";
    $valuesArr = $array();

foreach($myarray as $row) {
         $id = (int)$row[0]; // as my primary, auto increment
         $title = mysql_real_escape_string($row[1]);
         $body = mysql_real_escape_string($row[2]);
         $post_id = (int)$row[3];

         $valuesArr[] = "(`id`, `title`, `body`, `post_id`)";
         }

         $sql .=implode(',', $valuesArr);
         $db->query($sql);
}
```

please note that my `$id = (int)$row[0];` is primary and auto increment.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What does your query look like, what error message are you getting from the database?

Answer (score 2):

Construct the array with a key and a value

```
$myarray = array("id"=>'',"title"=>$title,"body"=>$body,"pid"=>$rowId);
```

and Use **PDO** instead of **mysql_*** functions (depreciated).

```
$sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `posts`(`id`, `title`, `body`, `post_id`) VALUES (:id,:title,:body,:pid)");
foreach($myarray as $row=>$value){
 $sql->bindValue(":".$row,$value);
}
$sql->execute();
```

More About **PDO** : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

in

$myarray = array('',**'$title','$body','$rowId'**);

code, you cannot use single quotations to read variables values in to string. you must use double quatations for that, because if you use single quotation, it not reading variable value, and php thinks its the value itself,

try

$myarray = array("",**"$title","$body","$rowId"**);

this may help you...

Answer (score 0):

The thing is:

- Maybe your code has some weird indent, but the first definition `insertToDB` neither appears to be properly  closed (maybe it is, at the end of the code section you provide) nor have a `return`. If it is properly closed, it still lacks a `return` (it may help you diagnose what is going on have conditional return for success and error cases.
- You define `$query` but do not use it later. Unless you append to that string the result of converting your array into another string (a thing that I dont see either), I dont think you are going to `INSERT` anything to your database.
- You need to loop through $valuesArr and build a string from your array.

Maybe I'm missing something...